# Using Formik causes an issue in my web App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I am creating a CRUD web app using node.js mySql and react. I have a table which is editable by creating new rows. I chose Formik to handle this.

I used this command to install it:
`npm install formik`

But when I created the JSX structure and ran the program to check that everything works, It displayed an error in the browser saying

`"Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component".`

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Field, Form } from 'formik';


function CreateRow() {

    return (
        <div className="form">
            <Formik>
                <Form>
                    <Field placeholder="Enter value..."/>
                </Form>
            </Formik>
        </div>
    );
}

export default CreateRow
```

I just cannot figure out what is the problem. I tried reinstalling Formik but with no success. When I delete the `import` statement and the Formik tags inside the div, this error does not appear, So I am not using invalid hooks anywhere else. I hope someone can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Usually the problem is that you import it in wrong way.
You should do:

```
import CreateRow from './path/to/file'
```

In the files where you import it, are you sure it is like that?

Comment: Yes I am sure, because it works if I take out the formik stuff